# Arch Linux on VirtualBox network problems

Tags: networking, virtualbox, archlinux

I've installed ArchLinux with VB on MacOS. I have network problems, I cannot resolve addresses. When trying pacman -S htop for example I get the following error :

:: Retrieving packages from extra...
error: failed retrieving file 'htop-1.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mir1.archlinux.fr : Could not resolve host: mir1.archlinux.fr; Name or service not known
warning: failed to retrieve some files from extra

```
error: failed to commit transaction (download library error)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

If I `ping mir1.archlinux.fr` I get a response. I'm running Network in Nat Mode.

PS: If I run In Bridge Mode I have no problems.

Can someone help me fixing this problem?

Comment: No firewalls. and no proxies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind... disabling ipv6 fixed the problem.!

Answer (score 0):

Check your /etc/resolve.conf or even change for opendns/google DNS.
Then check any domain like:

```
dig http://stackoverflow.com
```

finally:

```
pacman -Syu
```